# How to set the style of line comment in phpstorm

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, configure

How to change the default style of line comment in PHPStorm to at indentation level rather than at first column?

```
if ($condition) {
// At first column.
    // At indentation level
}
```

Comment: This question is really hard to properly parse. Can you please update it?

Comment: @Lizz Sorry, my English is too bad. I've updated, I hope you can understand it now.

Comment: It's not configurable -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14262; But there is an option to re-indent such comments on code reformat (check Code Style)

Comment: @LazyOne, why dont you post this as an answer. Sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can change this in "Options -> Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces" and check "Comment at first colum".

Comment: It is only in the new version.

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: It's bad solution... It works only on `Code reformat..` step and saves a lot of excess spaces...

Answer (score 55):

For "Ctrl+/" line commenting it is in "Settings->Code Style->PHP->Other->Code Commeting->Line comment at first column".

Comment: I'm a sucker for keyboard shortcuts and the accepted answer isn't enough, if you always use the keyboard comment function. This, on the other hand, did the trick for me! (Both PHPStorm 7.x and PHPStorm 8 EAP)

Comment: Now if it would only add a space `// My comment` instead of `//My Comment`

Comment: @RyanWinchester there's an option "Add a space at comment start" - in the 2016.2 version.

Comment: BTW. It's moved to Editor > Code Style > PHP in 2016.2

Comment: it is now in the "Code Generation" tab

Answer (score 49):

### Version 2017.3 and greater

Looking at this answer, noticed that it needs a little updating.
As of version 2017.3, this has been updated to:

Preferences > Editor > Code Style > PHP > (tab) Code Generation > Comment Code > (uncheck) Line comment at first column

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.