# PhpStorm - change single line comment character

Tags: php, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

When pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> the line that is selected will turn to a single line comment with `//`.

I want to make it so the `//` turns to a `#` sign in PhpStorm 2016. is it possible for php files?

```
line of code here
```

after <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> turns to

```
# line of code here
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you prefer # over // ?

Comment: It can be a visual aid to tell out comment-out code from actual documentation.

Comment: The option [should be with this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417962/how-to-set-the-style-of-line-comment-in-phpstorm#24662081) but it isn't. Perhaps it doesn't exist.

Comment: There are no such stuff. IDE recognize `#` as single line comment symbol but only uses `//` when generating them. I say -- go though available plugins and look for some that might do that

Comment: I like the `#`. its a little bit cleaner than `//` i think. so there is no reason above that. so there is no such thin in IDE out of the box? is there any plugins that you guys suggest? I could't find anything actually.

Comment: Feel free to file a feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: Can't you make a macro for that, and assign it a shortcut?